# Get field annotation throws access denied

Tags: java, annotations

[image: Annotation Access Denied]

Hello Guys,

I tried to get annotation from field in JDK 1.5 but I got the exception mentioned in the image above.

```
private WorkFlowHeader getFlowHeader(Field field)
    {
        for(Annotation annotationL:field.getAnnotations())
        {if(annotationL instanceof WorkFlowHeader)
            return (WorkFlowHeader) annotationL;
        }
        return null;
    }

@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface WorkFlowHeader {
}
```

Comment: Do you execute the application within an IDE? Which one?

Comment: I am using eclipse MARS